# R compare variances without separate values

Tags: r, variance

I need to compare the variances of several independent samples. I don't have the data stored in vectors. I only know the mean, standard deviation and the sample count of each sample. Does anyone know a way to test whether the variances are aqual with only those three statistics in R?

Comment: That sounds like a question for [Cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). If your data are known to be normal distributed you can use the simple [F-Test (see e.g. WIkipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test_of_equality_of_variances). That does not require the complete data sets. In case of non-normality maybe the [Bartletts test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartlett%27s_test) is your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an implementation of the [Bartlett test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartlett%27s_test) that doesn't require the samples only their sizes and standard errors or variances.
The arguments are

- `n` a vector of sample sizes;
- `S` a vector of standard errors or variances;
- `se` a logical value, if `TRUE` argument `S` are the standard errors, if `FALSE` they are the variances.

Tested below with data set `iris`.

```
Bartlett_test <- function(n, S, se = TRUE){
  dname <- deparse(substitute(S))
  N <- sum(n)
  k <- length(n)
  S2 <- if(se) S^2 else S
  S2p <- sum((n - 1)* S2)/(N - k)
  numer <- (N - k)*log(S2p) - sum((n - 1)*log(S2))
  denom <- 1 + (sum(1/(n - 1)) - 1/(N - k))/(3*(k - 1))
  statistic <- c(X2 = numer/denom)
  parameter <- k - 1
  p.value <- pchisq(statistic, df = parameter, lower.tail = FALSE)
  ht <- list(
    statistic = statistic,
    data.name = dname,
    parameter = parameter,
    p.value = p.value,
    method = "Bartlett test of homogeneity of variances",
    alternative = "there are at least two unequal variances"
  )
  class(ht) <- "htest"
  ht
}

n <- with(iris, tapply(Sepal.Length, Species, FUN = length))
s <- with(iris, tapply(Sepal.Length, Species, FUN = sd))
s2 <- with(iris, tapply(Sepal.Length, Species, FUN = var))
Bartlett_test(n, s)
Bartlett_test(n, s2, se = FALSE)
```